# How to calculate adjusted R2 score for non-linear models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression, ensemble-learning

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038820/how-to-calculated-the-adjusted-r2-value-using-scikit), the adjusted R2 score can be calculated via the following equation, where `n` is the number of samples, `p` is the number of parameters of the model.

```
adj_r2 = 1-(1-R2)*(n-1)/(n-p-1)
```

According this another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033720/python-sklearn-multiple-linear-regression-display-r-squared/42392200), we can get the number of parameters of our model with `model.coef_`.

However, for Gradient Boosting (GBM), it seems we cannot obtain the number of parameters in our model:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(100,10)
y = np.random.randn(100,1)

model = GradientBoostingRegressor()
model.fit(X,y)

model.coef_

output >>> 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4650e3f7c16c> in <module>
----> 1 model.coef_

AttributeError: 'GradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

After checking the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html?highlight=gradientboosting#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor), it seems GBM consists of different estimators. Is the number of estimators equals to the number of parameters?

Still, I cannot get the number of parameters for each individual estimator

```
model.estimators_[0][0].coef_


output >>> 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-27216ebb4944> in <module>
----> 1 model.estimators_[0][0].coef_

AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

How to calculate the adjusted R2 score for GBM?

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Comment: I am still reading about interpretative models, since you mention that R2 score should only be used to evaluate interpretative models. Can we find any interpretative models in sklearn? I guess linear regression, SVM, Gradient Boosting are not interpretative models.

Comment: Linear regression is - that's where the R2 concept was developed and used in the first place. Again, don't confuse the relatively recent discussion of interpetable ML models with what I say about interpretative *statistics* models. What I say is that R2 is practically not used in ML at all...

Comment: But in any case, the answer has arguably addressed you underlying *coding* issue, which the question was actually about. I could have stopped there instead of offering the extra advice (which was actually not asked for).

Comment: Alright. One last question, other than linear regression, can you name one more interpretative model? Maybe I would understand it more after reading one more example of interpretative model.

Comment: Not familiar with any, I'm afraid; I, too, am an ML practitioner, and not a statistician. Stats models that generalize LR (GLMs, GAMs) may be..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **don't do it** (notice that all the posts you link to are about *linear* regression).

---

Long answer:

To start with, your definition that

> `p` is the number of parameters of the model

is **not** correct. `p` is the number of explanatory variables used by the model ([source](http://(source).)).

In agreement to this definition, the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033720/python-sklearn-multiple-linear-regression-display-r-squared/42392200) you have linked to actually uses `X.shape[1]` instead of `model.coef_`; the latter is suggested in a comment, and it is not correct either (see own comment there).

So, if you insist on computing the r-squared for your GBM model, you can always adjust the code from the linked post (after getting your predictions `y_pred`), taking also advantage of scikit-learn `r2_score`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

y_pred = model.predict(X)
r_squared = r2_score(y, y_pred)
adjusted_r_squared = 1 - (1-r_squared)*(len(y)-1)/(len(y)-X.shape[1]-1)
```

But why you shouldn't do it? Well, quoting from an [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct/54618898#54618898) in another question:

> the whole R-squared concept comes in fact directly from the world of statistics, where the emphasis is on *interpretative* models, and it has little use in machine learning contexts, where the emphasis is clearly on *predictive* models; at least AFAIK, and beyond some very introductory courses, I have never (I mean *never*...) seen a predictive modeling problem where the R-squared is used for any kind of performance assessment; neither it's an accident that popular *machine learning* introductions, such as Andrew Ng's [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) at Coursera, do not even bother to mention it.